# TextView wont get pushed off the screen when keyboard comes in

Tags: android

I have the opposite problem of everyone else. I have a relative layout, and I'm aligning everything from bottom up, because when the keyboard comes in, I want everything in my screen to be pushed up, such that everything that was on the top half of the screen gets pushed out of view, and the stuff in the bottom of screen are visible and sitting on top of the keyboard. 
 The Image buttons I have at the top of the screen move out of the way fine, but the TextView gets stuck and refuses to be pushed off the view-able area, therefore collides with my other views.

[image]

and heres my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/cream_bg"
android:clickable="false"
tools:context="com.loop.ConnectProfileActivity">



<com.loop.CustomUi.LoopButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_connect_profile_manual"
    style="@style/WideBlueBtnStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:onClick="buttonHandler"
    android:text="@string/create_profile_manually"
    />




<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etLoginPassword"
    style="@style/editTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_connect_profile_manual"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etLoginPhoneNum"
    style="@style/editTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/etLoginPassword"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/largeSpace"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_phone_number"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForgotPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standardSpace"
    android:text="@string/ForgotPassword"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="buttonHandler"
    android:textColor="@color/navy_blue"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/etLoginPassword"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvConnectProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ConnectProfileText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/etLoginPhoneNum"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxWidth="270dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/connect_to_service"
    style="@style/darkGreyTextSans"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/largeSpace"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnConnectProfileFb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ConnectProfileText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingRight="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_connect_facebook"
    android:onClick="buttonHandler"
    android:background="@color/trans"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnConnectProfileGoog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ConnectProfileText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_connect_google"
    android:background="@color/trans"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" in activity in AndroidManifest? I tested your xml and works fine with windowSoftInputMode added.

Comment: @Wildroid Yes I did, and the weird thing is that the keyboard SOMETIMES obscures the EditText widget :(. its intermittent, if I click back and tap a few other things and go back to it, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. And by that I mean sometimes it will pan so that the keyboard is below the EditText, and sometimes the Keyboard will cover the EditText.

Comment: In that case, a work around would be to place the RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView. This way, the user can scroll to tap the login button. Also, I would hide the soft keyboard on Activity create so user would view the entire layout at first.